# Starting SSH server after VPN starts

Tags: vpn, openvpn, openssh, sshd

I am running an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 14.04 as well as OpenSSH.

I have my SSH server configured to bind to an IP address on my VPN interface. Once my machine boots, binding to that IP fails.

Once I log in, can see with `netstat` that `sshd` is not listening. I am able to restart `sshd` and the machine will start listening properly. The IP on my VPN is the only IP I have configured `sshd` to listen on.

At Boot:

```
sshd[1016]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
sshd[1016]: error: Bind to port 22 on 10.8.0.1 failed: Cannot assign requested address.
sshd[1016]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
```

Restart SSH:

```
sshd[3481]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
sshd[3481]: Server listening on 10.8.0.1 port 22.
```

My best guess is that `sshd` is starting before my VPN is up and running. Is there a way I am able to ensure `sshd` starts afterwards so it can bind properly?

Any suggestions about what to do or check?

Comment: There most likely is, but it will largely depend on your OS/distro. Please edit your question w/ that piece of information.

Comment: I have included it. It is on the first line. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

In the OpenVPN configuration file `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` you can specify a script to run on *up*. If you take a look at the OpenVPN manual page `man openvpn`, you will see `--up cmd`. In the `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` configuration file, I added a line:

```
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh"
```

This file is one that I created and will be executed when the VPN starts. Right now, mine looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
logger VPN is UP
service ssh restart
```

Now, every time my OpenVPN server starts up, it will also restart the OpenSSH server as well. Likewise, I am able to also use `--down cmd` and specify a file in the server configuration file if I wish to have a script executed when the server is shutdown.

You can read more about these in the OpenVPN manual page - `man openvpn`

Comment: How did you set up SSH to bind to the VPN interface?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 I achieved it without actually binding the interface. I bound it to the IP address i knew my machine would be on after connecting to the VPN. In this case, I was hosting the VPN so I knew what ip my machine (The VPN server) would have inside the VPN. From there, you just have ssh only listen on that ip address. I am not sure whether this is 100% reliable. It was for me, but i would imagine interface binding would be better. Please comment if you learn how to bind.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the problem is with my client.  I can connect to the VPN then run SSH with no problems on one client but not with another.  The problem client is running Lubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ssh uses upstart, but openvpn doesn't ... you might be able to force ssh to come up delayed by doing this, but it's untested (I don't want to mess up my install):

```
update-rc.d ssh defaults 99
```

And as it's untested: **CAVEAT EMPTOR**